# Imprint Shape to another Mesh

Tags: boolean-modifier

[image: Having the circle shape in my complex mesh to - for instance - give this area a different material]Imagine you have a complex Mesh and you would like to have perfect circles inside the complex Mesh which you can extrude accordingly. First thing that came to my mind was to do it with the Boolean Modifier with a Cylinder to get the Circles in my Mesh. However, I don't want to get holes in my mesh nor do I want to fill in the hole with F on my own then. I just want to have the additional edges in my Mesh, that are basically the imprint of the Cylinder. It's like you would make a stamp on paper without cutting in. Is there a simple solution for that?

Comment: you can use knife projet with a circle projected on your mesh

Comment: It's difficult to imagine what you want to do to be honest although my first thought would be to add your circle in Edit mode which would mean that it's part of the same object.. Can you add an image or annotation of what you want into your question? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: I've added the image for clarification

Comment: If you want your circle on the surface of your mesh I agree with @lemon (use [knife project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.5#knife-project)) but you didn't make that clear in your initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can knife project the circle:

[image]

Place the circle facing the mesh.

Enter edit mode for the mesh.

Select the circle in the outliner.

Use 'knife projet' from the 'mesh' menu.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Aggrise if the answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)